# Can't to run games .ISO on PCSX(Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: games, iso, emulation

I try to run ps1 games on PSCX using by .ISO file And i already set SCPH1001.BIN.

but stuck on this error:

```
CD ROM failed
The CD does not appear to be a valid Playstation CD
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the iso is not corrupted. 
I use the same emulator (V 1.9.92) with these settings:

/Graphics - XVideo Driver 1.1.17

/Sound - SDL Sound 1.6.0

/Controller 1 and 2 - Gamepad/Keyboard Input 1.1.0

/CD-ROM - CD-ROM Drive Reader 1.0.0

/BIOS- Simulate PSX BIOS

mayority are default configs and work fine for me.